# Vlocity Interaction Launcher - VF Page called from Verify button

Tags: vlocity

I am using Vlocity Launch Interaction for a Healthcare application.

Upon IVR call connection, agent verifies the caller details and clicks the OOTB Verify button.

Upon Inspect element, I am seeing a managed package VF page coming up but I am not sure from where it is getting called.

If anyone is familiar with this OOTB feature, can you please help?